# Source not found Error and App closes Abruptly

Tags: java, android, debugging, button, android-intent

I'm new to Android programming and have been searching this problem for a day now and couldn't come up with a solution. Kindly help me in solving this small problem which is creating a big problem for me.

The error is that when I press the login button in my `MainActivity`, the app says that unfortunately it has stopped working and the debug window shows an error `"Source not found"` and further it says `ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, Intent) line: 2249`

I've seen similar posts related to this but those posts couldn't help me.
Following my code.

#### Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   package="com.example.firstapp"
   android:versionCode="1"
   android:versionName="1.0" >

   <uses-sdk
       android:minSdkVersion="8"
       android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

   <application
       android:allowBackup="true"
       android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
       android:label="@string/app_name"
       android:theme="@style/Theme.Base.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar" >


       <activity
           android:name=".MainActivity"
           android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
           <intent-filter>
               <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
               <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
           </intent-filter>
       </activity>
       <activity
           android:name=".Second"
           android:label="@string/title_activity_second" >
       </activity>
       <activity
           android:name=".Registration"
           android:label="@string/title_activity_registration" >
       </activity>
   </application>

   </manifest>
```

#### MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_id);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Second.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
        final Button button2=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button2_id);
        button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent j = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Registration.class);
                startActivity(j);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

#### MainActivity_xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
   android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
   android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
   android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
   tools:context="com.example.firstapp.MainActivity" >

 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1"
    android:text="Welcome To Foodparkk"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button_id"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_marginTop="45dp"
    android:contentDescription="@null"
    android:src="@drawable/robo" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_id"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView3"
    android:text="Login" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText3"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button2_id"
    android:text="E-Mail"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText3"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText3"
    android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
    android:text="Password"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textPassword" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textEmailAddress" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2_id"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/button_id"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button_id"
    android:layout_marginBottom="42dp"
    android:text="Register" />

 </RelativeLayout>
```

#### activity_second.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
   android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
   android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
   android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
   tools:context="com.example.firstapp.Second">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/spinner1"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="44dp"
    android:text="Select your Meal"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="25dp" />

 </RelativeLayout>
```

#### Second.java

```
public class Second extends ActionBarActivity implements OnItemSelectedListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
        // Create an ArrayAdapter using the string array and a default spinner layout
        ArrayAdapter&lt;CharSequence&gt; adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
        R.array.food_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        // Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        // Apply the adapter to the spinner
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView&lt;?&gt; parent, View view, int position,long id) {
        String item = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
        // Showing selected spinner item
        Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), "Selected: " + item, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected (AdapterView&lt;?&gt; parent) {
        // code
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please post your xml file

Comment: @archon92-I did that,plz check

Comment: Have you created "Second" and Registeration activites???I dont see those classes in your code....if you have created them please post them as well..otherwise if you have not created them ,when you launch your intent when u click the login button ,The system will look for "Second.class" and when no activity named second is present,it will crash

Comment: Second activity is present,I added the xml code for that,plz check

Comment: You need to write java code for second.class and then set the layout of activity_second.xml in setContentview() method of second activity

Comment: possible duplicate of [The app closes abruptly as soon as Login Button is pressed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27367213/the-app-closes-abruptly-as-soon-as-login-button-is-pressed)

Comment: @BenPearson-That case hasnt been solved yet

Comment: @archon92-I added the second.java file ..plz check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your second.java class you are referencing your layout of main activity

```
public class Second extends ActionBarActivity implements OnItemSelectedListener {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

Change SetContentView to

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);
```

Answer (score 0):

A "Source Not Found" error will be thrown when a class or activity can't be found or instantiated.

Please add the **full** LogCat log or at least the full ErrorStack.